# Migrate TFS 2010 to 2012 - migrate custom controls in web access

Tags: upgrade

We have developed custom contols for TFS 2010, which deployed to visual studio and web access.
After update TFS to 2012 custom contols missed in web access.
Custom controls written in c# and it seems that it need to be rewritten to client javascript
([instruction to create controls in javascript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/serkani/archive/2012/06/22/work-item-custom-control-development-in-tf-web-access-2012-development.aspx))

Is exist way to use server controls in TFS 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible. Web Access received a total refresh and is now much snappier as it ever has been. To be able to achieve that, it has been build from the ground up based on other technology.

This had a trade off that existing control need to be rewritten. I am so sorry that there is not a better answer for you right now.